# How can I install ubuntu to SD card?

Tags: boot, asus, sd-card

I'm trying to install ubuntu 13.10 directly on my SD card to save energy and use HDD just for data, but I've some problem. I've created a startup disk in my SD with unebootin. I've disabled efi, set SD as first choice in boot, but when I restart the PC, it automatically returns to the screen boot.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Install ubuntu for example from USB key, (Unetbootin) and during instalation process choose your SD card as a destination for your system.

Comment: didn't work!
when i proceed with the instalation the program crash.

Comment: And how big SD card do you use? In my opinion it`s not good idea use SD card instead of HDD.